# How to write the commits of a remote branch to my local branch?

Tags: git

I have a remote branch, let's called it `FIN-985_the_original`. I have my local branch, which is called `FIN-985_v2`. `FIN-985_v2` is a branch from master.

I did two commands and I'm confused as one clearly gave me what I want

First one is the one below

```
git rebase --onto FIN-985_the_original FIN-985_v2
```

This one put the content of `FIN-985_the_original` into `FIN-985_v2`, issue is it seems to replace the contents of `FIN-985_the original` into `FIN-985_v2`, wiping out the commits done into `FIN-985_v2`.

The second part seems to give me what I want but it kind of defy my logic

```
git checkout FIN-985_the_original
git rebase FIN-985_v2
```

I was expecting that the the rebase would be done on FIN-985_v2 and instead, it was done on `FIN-985_the_original`. From my command, I know it makes sense as the checkout was done on `FIN-985_the_original` but it bugs my logic as I've read [this](https://akrabat.com/the-beginners-guide-to-rebasing-your-pr/)

Any tips are more than welcomed to deconfuse me.

Cheers

Comment: Side note: you have a space in your hypothetical branch name. This is invalid as a branch name, but also confusing, because in the command line, spaces separate different arguments. Call it `the_original` or `the-original` or just drop the word `the` to eliminate this particular problem...

Comment: Hi @torek there you go. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic rebase (your second case)**

I'll start with your second case, since that's the easier one to explain.

```
git checkout A
git rebase B
```

asks Git to take any commits in A that are not in B, and move them to the end of B.

Sample scenario:

```
-- 0 (master)
    \
     1 -- 2 -- 3 (B)
      \
       4 -- 5 (A)
```

If, while A is checked out, I do `git rebase B`, I pluck commits 4 and 5 (they're on A but not on B) and move them to the end of B:

```
-- 0 (master)
    \
     1 -- 2 -- 3 (B)
                \
                 4' -- 5' (A)
```

So now A will have all the commits of B followed by the commits of A.

In your case, the commits of `the_original` should now be after those of `v2`, and `the_original` should be a branch of `v2`, although I'm not sure that's what you're saying happened.

**Using --onto**

When you use `--onto`, things get weird. I'll start with a `checkout` again because the branch that is currently checked out still is the one being moved:

```
git checkout A
git rebase --onto C B
```

asks Git to take the commits that are on A but not on B and move them, same as without `--onto`. But now, we gave the rebase a destination: put them at the end of C.

Let's add C to my initial scenario:

```
     6 (C)
    /
-- 0 (master)
    \
     1 -- 2 -- 3 (B)
      \
       4 -- 5 (A)
```

Since I'm on A, we're still going to move 4 and 5: they're on A but not on B; but we'll place them on C, i.e., after 6:

```
       6 (C)
      / \
     /   4' -- 5' (A)
    /
-- 0 (master)
    \
     1 -- 2 -- 3 (B)
```

So in your case, what should have happened depends on what was checked out before the rebase: the commits in the branch that was checked out that were not in `v2` should have gotten moved to the end of `the_original`.

I find I rarely want `--onto`, and frankly I find it confusing enough that I would probably cherry pick the commits around instead of using `git rebase --onto`...

**Pedantic notes**

Following the convention at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase, I'm using ' to mark the moved commits, since 4' and 5' are new commits reproducing 4 and 5, not 4 and 5 themselves.

I'm taking a linguistic shortcut when I say "moved": commits are not technically moved, they are re-applied, thus creating new commits that look more or less the same as the originals.